# My Riley has gone away

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Here is my first Riley riddle. hope you like it!

> My prefix has a six-pack,
>
> My infix would be you in Turkey,
>
> My suffix thinks: "Nice - I am very.",
>
> And altogether I am not there.

Comment: Is the title, My Riley is "gone" away, intentional ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its -

> Absent or absentee, **New Guess:** Absence

Prefix-

> Abs , six pack abs

Infix-

> Sen , its literally you in Turkish language.

Suffix-

> Still not sure, maybe nce, nice, minus the i (as in varies by an I)

Last line & Title-

> gone away and not here both refers to absence.

Comment: Very very close. your first two are correct, but you're missing the suffix which will  get you exactly correct. It's not absent or absentee, but more Hint: there this many space in the word _ _ _ _ _ _ _

Comment: Now it's correct! The suffix meant rot13(Nyy gung zrnag jnf avpr - v cyhf fbzr svyyre grkg.)